# Black screen when logging in to AD enabled computer

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, active-directory

- Network drives not working
- Icons on desktop not showing properly (broken icons)
- Slow start up time with "black screen" for longer period of time

I got two users with this issue, any idea what might be the problem?
No viruses found, Computer works great when logging in as any other user.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2010/01/13/3305263.aspx) referenced by @TODDA-SPEOT-IS is a good start.

If roaming profile is used, check to see if it is very large.  If possible, delete the profile (back it up first) and allow it to recreate.

Are there mapped drives or printers that are not available.  Windows will look for these and that takes time.  If possibl, delete any printers that no longer exist or file shares that no longer exist

Comment: Our solution was simple: we killed the profile and had the user login again. Not optimal and quite time consuming but did the job